# ARCore Unity Android | HelloAR app crashed when running on Phone

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, arcore

I followed the instructions on this page
https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/unity/quickstart-android
and got this error when running on phone after the installation.

I am a newbie to ARCore. Can anyone help me?

```
11-20 14:20:45.629 15984 16006 E native  : ARCore Fatal Error
11-20 14:20:45.629 15984 16006 E native  : Copy paste the block below until END
11-20 14:20:45.629 15984 16006 E native  : ###################### BUILD ID ######################
11-20 14:20:45.629 15984 16006 E native  :  BUILD_USERNAME build-secure BUILD_HOSTNAME oxf6.prod.google.com BUILD_DIRECTORY /export/hda3/borglet/remote_hdd_fs_dirs/rabbit-prod.secure-alloc.build-secure.113.536079300067.14b334fb3717c109/mount/tmpfs/rabbit/workspaces/11337855945316597703/google3 BUILD_EMBED_LABEL arcore_1.13_20191007_RC010 BUILD_BLAZE_RELEASE release blaze-2019.09.28-1 (mainline @271678982) WORKSPACE_STATUS_COMMAND_ARGUMENT /export/hda3/borglet/remote_hdd_fs_dirs/rabbit-prod.secure-alloc.build-secure.113.536079300067.14b334fb3717c109/mount/tmpfs/rabbit/workspaces/11337855945316597703/-oxf6-a188-33362-107a9504df02b-595b4d851bebd_embed_changelist_ VERIFIABLE 1 BUILD_CLIENT build-secure-info:source-uri BUILD_DEPOT_PATH //depot/branches/vr_arcore_release_branch/273204670.2/google3 BUILD_CLIENT_MINT_STATUS 1 BUILD_USERNAME vr-builder BUILD_DIRECTORY /google/src/files/276618081/depot/branches/vr_arcore_release_branch/273204670.2/OVERLAY_READONLY/google3 BUILD_ID a628e9ed-44d4-4db7-94e6-109043b4f5bc BUILD_REQUEST_ID bbq-9384cf0e-873d-4d93-8057-6a439341c962 SRCFSD_TASK_BNS /bns/ox/borg/ox/bns/build-secure/rabbit-prod.secure-srcfsd/113 BUILDRABBIT_DEBUG_BBQID http://go/bbqid?uuid=bbq-9384cf0e-873d-4d93-8057-6a439341c962 BUILDRABBIT_TASK_BNS /bns/ox/borg/ox/bns/build-secure/rabbit-prod.secure-worker/113 BUILD_BASELINE_CHANGELIST 273204670 BUILDRABBIT_DEBUG_BUILD_ID http://go/buildrabbit-build-id/a628e9ed-44d4-4db7-94e6-109043b4f5bc SOURCE_URI googlefile:/google_src/files/276618081/depot/branches/vr_arcore_release_branch/273204670.2/OVERLAY_READONLY/google3 BUILDRABBIT_BLAZE_BINARY_PATH /google/src/files/276618081/depot/branches/vr_arcore_release_branch/273204670.2/OVERLAY_READONLY/google3/tools/blaze BUILD_REQUEST_ID bbq-9384cf0e-873d-4d93-8057-6a439341c962 OBJFSD_TASK_BNS /bns/ox/borg/ox/bns/build-secure/rabbit-prod.secure-objfsd/113 BUILD_VERSION_MAP map 0 { // } BUILD_CHANGELIST 276618081 BUILD_WORKER_VERSION buildrabbit-worker_20191018_0_RC00 BUILDRABBIT_DEBUG_LOG_ARCHIVE_DIR http://cnsviewer/cns/ox-d/home/build-logs/log_archives/a6/a628e9ed-44d4-4db7-94e6-109043b4f5bc
11-20 14:20:45.629 15984 16006 E native  : ######################## BEGIN #######################
11-20 14:20:45.629 15984 16006 E native  : ARCoreError: third_party/arcore/ar/core/android/implementation/session_create_implementation.cc:335 https://cs.corp.google.com/piper///depot/google3/third_party/arcore/ar/core/android/implementation/session_create_implementation.cc?g=0&l=335
11-20 14:20:45.629 15984 16006 E native  : ######################### END ########################
11-20 14:20:45.629 15984 16006 E native  :
11-20 14:20:45.629 15984 16006 E native  : session_manager.cc:57 ArPresto::ArCore session creation failed.
11-20 14:20:45.629 15984 16006 E CRASH   : signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000007
11-20 14:20:45.629 15984 16006 E CRASH   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
11-20 14:20:45.629 15984 16006 E CRASH   : Build type 'Release', Scripting Backend 'mono', CPU 'armeabi-v7a'
11-20 14:20:45.629 15984 16006 E CRASH   : Build fingerprint: 'HONOR/LLD-AL20/HWLLD-H2:9/HONORLLD-AL20/9.1.0.115C00:user/release-keys'
11-20 14:20:45.629 15984 16006 E CRASH   : Revision: '0'
11-20 14:20:45.629 15984 16006 E CRASH   : pid: 15984, tid: 16006, name: UnityMain  >>> com.LeoCool.TestModel <<<
11-20 14:20:45.629 15984 16006 E CRASH   :     r0 00000179  r1 ffffffff  r2 00000000  r3 bef87239
11-20 14:20:45.629 15984 16006 E CRASH   :     r4 c6de21c0  r5 c6b7f5c4  r6 c6de21c0  r7 00000000
11-20 14:20:45.630 15984 16006 E CRASH   :     r8 ce2b5f10  r9 80808080  sl 00000000  fp 00000000
11-20 14:20:45.630 15984 16006 E CRASH   :     ip ce2eed6c  sp cf97e4e0  lr ce2bebe9  pc bef87242  cpsr 00003e86
11-20 14:20:45.630 15984 16006 E CRASH   :
11-20 14:20:45.630 15984 16006 E CRASH   : backtrace:
11-20 14:20:45.731 15984 16006 E CRASH   :      #00  pc 00ca7242  /data/app/com.google.ar.core-YBNwcR_XNQpRS7RrkxKBaw==/lib/arm/libarcore_c.so (ArConfig_setUpdateMode+4283838473)
11-20 14:20:45.731 15984 16006 E CRASH   :      #01  pc 00002be5  /data/app/com.LeoCool.TestModel--yA5ojiw7Ii-vCVU8PCQeQ==/lib/arm/libarpresto_api.so
11-20 14:20:45.731 15984 16006 E CRASH   :      #02  pc 00001899  /data/app/com.LeoCool.TestModel--yA5ojiw7Ii-vCVU8PCQeQ==/lib/arm/libarpresto_api.so
11-20 14:20:45.731 15984 16006 E CRASH   :      #03  pc 0000163b  /data/app/com.LeoCool.TestModel--yA5ojiw7Ii-vCVU8PCQeQ==/lib/arm/libarpresto_api.so
11-20 14:20:45.731 15984 16006 E CRASH   :      #04  pc 00000505  /data/app/com.LeoCool.TestModel--yA5ojiw7Ii-vCVU8PCQeQ==/lib/arm/libarpresto_api.so (ArPresto_update+4294889492)
11-20 14:20:45.731 15984 16006 E CRASH   :      #05  pc 000084d4   ( (wrapper managed-to-native) GoogleARCoreInternal.ARCoreAndroidLifecycleManager/ExternApi:ArPresto_update () {0xc6c56330} + 0x34 (0xef2c34a0 0xef2c3524) [0xee86ef00 - Unity Root Domain]+34004)
```

Comment: Error looks similar to this reported issue: https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/issues/350. Some discussion on error like this suggest resetting phone to factory defaults and trying again works - not a great solution but maybe possible if you are using a test phone.

Comment: I fixed this by resetting the device to factory settings and reinstalling the Google AR Core Services